# Angular Material highlights when chevron is clicked but not when text is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-nested-tree-node (click)="activeNode = node" *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, node)">
        <div class="mat-tree-node" (click)="filterDevices(node)"  matTreeNodeToggle>
            <div (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, node)" [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight': activeNode === node }">
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="activeNode = node"
                    [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name">
                    <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                    </mat-icon>
                </button>
                {{node.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul [class.tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
    </li>
</mat-nested-tree-node>
```

[Image of Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N93zW.png)

As can be seen in the tree, the node is highlighted in yellow but it only highlights when the chevron is clicked not when the text 'Assembly' is clicked. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but you've got two click events on mat-tree-node.

Try change this piece of code

```
 <mat-tree-node (click)="activeNode = node" *matTreeNodeDef="let node" (click)="filterDevices(node)"...
```

into

```
 <mat-tree-node (click)="activeNode = node; filterDevices(node)" *matTreeNodeDef="let node"...
```

Comment: No, the mat-tree-nodes are getting highlighted properly, it's the mat-nested-tree nodes that aren't being highlighted upon selection.

Answer (score 0):

So, the fix was to put the `(click)="activeNode = node; filterDevices(node)"` in the top div instead of having it inside the icon button since the text was not contained inside the icon button. Code is as follows:

```
<mat-nested-tree-node (click)="activeNode = node" *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, node)">
        <div class="mat-tree-node" (click)="activeNode = node; filterDevices(node)"  matTreeNodeToggle>
            <div (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, node)" [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight': activeNode === node }">
                <button mat-icon-button 
                    [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name">
                    <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                    </mat-icon>
                </button>
                {{node.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul [class.tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
    </li>
</mat-nested-tree-node>
```